# How to display result on same page?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
function selectFunction(letter){
  document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = "Selection is : " + letter;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Event on list of elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="select">
<form>
 <select onchange="selectFunction(this.value)"> 
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
 </select>
</form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to java script, what I need to do here is that when one of the option is clicked result is on the same page, and that every time when I click another letter page shows a new result. I have no clue how to do this. I tried doing `.innerHTML+=` but that shows a bunch of results, and I want a clean page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, is it because when the `select` div is populated with the letter selection that the `select` element is lost?

If so, you could have a dedicated element to store the selection:

```
<div id="select">
    <div id="result">Selection will appear here</div>

    <form>
        <select onchange="selectFunction(this.value)">  
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectFunction(letter){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Selection is : " + letter;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

It might also be handy to add the `value` to your options, e.g.

```
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
```

and lastly, adding an empty option since the change event won't work for `A` because it is the first option, you'd have to select another option then select `A` again.

```
<option value="">Select letter:</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
```

Comment: Dedicated, element to store the selection. Yes yes, stupid me. Thanks, it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the HTML of your `select` div, what you have to do is to create a child node with the text you calculated, and then append it to the HTML of `select` div

Here is what you should do

```js
function selectFunction(letter){
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Selection is : " + letter);
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              // 
  document.getElementById("select").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Event on list of elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="select">
<form>
 <select onchange="selectFunction(this.value)"> 
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
 </select>
</form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```